# How to plot hist with log scale

Tags: matlab

```
x = [1: 1000]
hist(x)
```

then, there are figure showing the histogram, but if i set the axes property and Y-axis to log. I cannot see anything in the figure. How to plot the histogram with log scale.

Answer (score 7):

Try `set(gca, 'Xscale',  'log')` for plotting log on X axis. It worked for me I am using 7.12.0 or 2011a. Check the [axis reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html) for more help.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using histc with log edges and barplot

```
help histc
-- Function File: N = histc (Y, EDGES)

matlab> edges=log(1:100:1000); 
matlab> h=histc(x,edges)
matlab> bar(1:100:1000, h)
```

Comment: You have to add 'histc' option with bar to keep histc edges feature : bar(1:100:1000, h, 'histc')

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it's not available as a native matlab function:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2ZUTKK/?solution=1-2ZUTKK

But this article also explains several workarrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function semilogxhist(val,M)
% semilogxhist - generate histogram with M bars and log-scale x axis
if nargin<2; M=min(30,sqrt(length(val))); end
vmin=min(val); vmax=max(val);
edges=vmin*(vmax/vmin).^([0:M]/M);
count=histc(val,edges); 
if size(count,2)==1, count=count'; end 
x=edges(sort([1:M 1:M])); 
y=[0 count(sort([1:M-1 1:M-1])) 0];
% outline only: semilogx(x, y, '-');
plot(x, y, '-'); fill(x, y, 'b'); set(gca,'XScale','log');
```