# Changing the axis of a histogram plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to simulate values that represent a geometric distribution. The plot I have done using the code below seems to produce the right plot. But I want the x axis is badly out of position  and also I want the x-axis to be numbered 1,2,3,etc instead of the 10,20,30,etc that I receive now. I also want to plot the Y-axis as a log scale.I am trying to get the plot of 'X' given in the code.

```
%Geometric Distribution%
N=100;%Number of simulation
P=0.1;
X=zeros(N,1);%simulation data
Ti=0;%Counter

for Ti=2:N
  U=rand(1);
  a=log10(U);
  b=log10(1-P);
  c=(a/b);
  d=1+round(c);
  X(Ti)=d;
  Ti=Ti+1;
end

t = 0:N-1;
hist(X);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hist(X,min(X):max(X))`

[image]

Comment: When I use the x-axis as 10,20,30,etc I get the shape I want. But when I use this the shape is horrible wrong. I cant figure out how to upload the histogram, else I could show the shape I want

Comment: you can do: hist(X,n), n will be the number of bins. So you can adjust n to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting a bar graph with log scale is tricky. See: [How to plot hist with log scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812899/how-to-plot-hist-with-log-scale) , or use this:

```
[n, xout] = hist(X,0:max(X));
bar(xout, n, 'barwidth', 1, 'basevalue', 1);
set(gca,'YScale','log')
```