# How to increase bar width without overlapping in a MATLAB bar graph?

Tags: matlab, graph, bar-chart, overlapping

How can you increase the width of the bars in a bar graph in MATLAB without causing the bars to overlap? The script below increases the bar width but the bars overlap:

```
graph = [ 1 2 ; 3 4 ; 5 6 ; 7 8 ];
bar(graph,'BarWidth',2);
```

Comment: Have a look here: [How to plot hist with log scale](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6812899) or here: [Log scale (x axis) histogram](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11933787)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is via multiple calls to bar.

```
function h=BarSpecial(data, overallWidth )
    colour = {'r','b'};
    [r,c] = size(data);
    h = zeros(c,1);
    width = overallWidth / c;
    offset = [-width/2 width/2];
    for i=1:c
        h(i) = bar(data(:,i),'FaceColor',colour{i},'BarWidth',width);   
        set(h(i),'XData',get(h(i),'XData')+offset(i));
        hold on               
    end    
end
```

The following will generate a bar chart with the bars occupying 90% of the total space.

```
BarSpecial(graph,0.9)
```

The function BarSpecial as written is not general purpose but could be extended to handle a wider range of input data.

Answer (score 1):

Default width is = 0.8. 
If width is 1, the bars within a group touch one another. 
Values > 1 produce overlapping bars.

set width less than 1.
e.g.

```
figure; bar(graph,0.4);
```

Comment: 0.4 is the value pertaining to the percentage of space that the bar takes up in the total space allotted to it (0.4 = 40%; 1 = 100%). So this does not change the size of the total space, but changes the size of the percentage of that total space used for the bar. Setting it to anything above 1 makes it 100+%, which increases total size...but this causes overlaps. How do I change the total space size without the overlapping?